SharePoint 2019 Extending Web Application Breaks Sites
I am trying to extend a SharePoint 2019 Web Application in order to support SSO through Entra App Proxy.
When I extend my SharePoint 2019 Web Application I can see that a new site is created in IIS, however, both my current SharePoint 2019 Site and my new extended SharePoint 2019 are broken.
Looking at the console in Chrome reveals a ton of Javascript errors.
I have found that if I remap all of the virtual directories in both the current and new IIS site I can get them to bring up my SharePoint site.
However, there are some remaining issues.

On the main SharePoint Site, when I navigate to "Site Settings", I get a 401 error. However, on other sites within the same Site Collection I can get to "Site Settings" without an issue.
As I go deeper into the main SharePoint Site structure, sites start to exhibit additional js file missing errors that seem like they should be available looking at IIS.

From what I can tell Extending a SharePoint Web Application shouldn't result in anything breaking and should be fairly automatic.
This SharePoint installation has bene around a long time and has been upgraded from at least SharePoint 2013 and likely has some gremlins in it.
Do you have any suggestions how to get the Extend feature working?
Thank You!
